# UserInput function

Tags: r

I wrote a code that cats some answer from the user and executes a function, but my condition is too poor.
if the answer it is `yes` execute function x, if the answer is `no`, jump function x.
The problem is that any answer but `yes` jumps function x

The original code

```
userInput <- function(question) {
  cat(question)
  con <- file("stdin")
  on.exit(close(con))
  n <- readLines(con, n = 1)
  return(n)
}

if (opt$indexBuild) {
  if (!file.exists(file.path(paste(index_Folder, '/', 'Genome', sep = '')))) {
    index_genom <- star.index.function()
  }else{
    write(paste("Index genome files already exists."), stderr())
    if (casefold(userInput("Would you like to delete and re-run index generation? (yes or no) "), upper = FALSE) == 'yes') {
      index_genom <- star.index.function()
    }
  }
}
```

I've tried using while looping but no success.

```
userInput <- function(question) {
  cat(question)
  con <- file("stdin")
  on.exit(close(con))
  n <- readLines(con, n = 1)
  return(n)
}

    if (opt$indexBuild) {
      if (!file.exists(file.path(paste(index_Folder, '/', 'Genome', sep = '')))) {
        index_genom <- star.index.function()
      }else{
        write(paste("Index genome files already exists."), stderr())
        while (casefold((!(userInput("Would you like to delete and re-run index generation? (yes or no) ") %in% c('yes', 'no'))))) {
          write(paste("You should specify 'yes' or 'no' "), stderr())

        }

        index_genom <- star.index.function()
      }

    }
```

opt$indexBuild it is an external parameter.

The output is "fine". It is doing kind of what I expect, but if the answer is `yes` or `no` the code executes the same function.

[(Fig.1) If the answer it is not yes or no, keeping ask, if yes execute `index_genom <- star.index.function()`. this it is correct.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2K4ed.png)

[(Fig.2) If the answer it is not yes or no, keeping ask, if no execute `index_genom <- star.index.function()`. this it is not correct.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7OIqR.png)

Comment: Where is `userInput` from? Also, I don't see any condition that checks the user input. You just have a while loop that makes sure the input is either yes or no, but `star.index.function()` is run in both cases.

Comment: I've edited the code with the userInput function. Sorry.
The condition that check yes or no it is in the statement of the while.
`casefold((!(userInput("Would you like to delete and re-run index generation? (yes or no) ") %in% c('yes', 'no'))))`

That is the problem. I have to set a condition inside the while to execute `star.index.function()` if yes or jump if no

Comment: You need to capture the user input and then put an if/else around the second call to `star.index.function()`. The while loop only ensures that the answer is either *yes* or *no* - it doesn't specify what should be done in either case.

Comment: Thanks, gersht. I've tried to capture the userinput answer, but I don't know how.
If I set a condition inside the while with the userIpmut function the code will ask the question again.

Comment: Okay, I've provided an answer below. Don't forget to accept it  by clicking the ✓ if it helps you so others know what worked for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a loop in which you capture the user input and then do different things depending on what that input is. For instance, you could rewrite your while loop to do something like this (note that I've replaced `userInput` with `readline` because the former didn't work for me):

```r
repeat {
    inp <- casefold(readline("Delete and generate new index? (yes/no) -> "))

    if (inp %in% c("yes", "no")) break
    else write("Specify 'yes' or 'no'", stderr())
}

if (inp == "yes") index_genom <- star.index.function()
```

As you can see, I've saved the user input to `inp`, only leave the loop when `inp` is either *yes* or *no*, and then I call `index_genom <- star.index.function()` if `inp == "yes"`.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much, gersht.
You code works on the R terminal, but doesn't on the linux terminal. I think its because the `readline()` function, so I've edited it using my `userImput()` function. I wasnt thinking about the `repeat`looping.

Thank you again

```
repeat {
  inp <- userInput("Would you like to delete and re-run index generation? (yes or no) ")

  if (inp %in% c("yes", "no")) break()
  else write("Specify 'yes' or 'no'", stderr())
}

if (inp == "yes") index_genom <- star.index.function()
```